# References of the same author under the same shorthand

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, thesis, bibliographystyle

I want to group same author' works under the same shorthand.
For example: [image]

while with the code in the MWE I've gained:[image]

This is the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
            \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
            \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,english}
            \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}
            \setkeys{latin}{variant=modern}

  \usepackage[%
            bibstyle=philosophy-verbose,%
            citestyle=authoryear,%
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber,%
            classical = true,%
            scauthors = bibcite,%
            dashed = true,%trattino al posto del nome dell'autore nelle entrate multiple
            volnumformat = parens,%
            volumeformat = Roman,%
            firstinits=true,%
            volnumformat=strings,%
            volumeformat=romansc,%
            sorting=nyt,%
            relatedformat=brackets,%
            editionformat=superscript,
            indexing]{biblatex}
            
            \usepackage{polyglossia} 
            \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
            \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,english}
            \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}
            \setkeys{latin}{variant=modern}
            
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{pipi,
keywords = {edizione},
title = {Le Pitiche},
author = {Pindaro},
editor = {Bruno Gentili and Paola Angela Bernardini and Ettore Cingano and Pietro Giannini},
address = {Milano},
year = {1995},
shorthand = {Pi.}
}

@book{piol,
keywords = {edizione},
title = {Le Olimpiche},
author = {Pindaro},
editor = {Bruno Gentili and Paola Angela Bernardini and Ettore Cingano and Pietro Giannini},
address = {Milano},
year = {1995},
shorthand = {Pi.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbiblist{shorthand}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I want to do this 'cause I want to group entries under the same author's shorthand, even if in text, for example, I cite *Pi., Ol.* and *Pi.,P.*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Usually the idea of a `shorthand` is to refer to a unique work with a short designator. So two different works with the same `shorthand` are not the intended use case. Can you explain the motivation behind using `shorthand` here? How should the two entries be cited?

Comment: You've got a repeated section of code in your MWE (for `polyglossia`).

Comment: `Pi., Ol. and Pi.,P.` What code are you using to produce that?

Comment: I use /cite[/emph{Ol.}]{piol} e /cite[/emph{P.}]{pipi}

Comment: Why not `shortauthor`? You really don't want to be hard-coding the reference that way. That's literally what bibliography management software is for. And it matters to readers that your labels are unique.

Comment: I don't use shortauthor because I want that "Pi." on the left and I don't be able to print this if I don't use shorthand